# How would I find f'(x)?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Given the following equation$f(x+h)-f(x) = 7hx - 2h + h^2$, find $f'(x)$.

I have tried to rearrange the equation but I cannot figure out how to eliminate h and move towards the derivative.

Any assistance would be highly appreciated!

Comment: What is the *definition* of $f'(x)$?

Comment: Derivative? Yes?

Comment: The definition is a *limit*. Do you know what the definition is?

Comment: I see. So how would I treat the following problem then?

Comment: You should start by writing down the definition *here*.

Comment: Do you mean differentiation by first principles? Is that what I am supposed to apply here. I am not entirely sure what you mean by the "definition"?

Comment: Yes, it is. I mean that you really ought to know something that looks like $$f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} ....$$

Comment: Yes, I know what you are referring to. So you are saying I should rearrange it into that form?

Comment: @user296602 Ok I think I got it. The answer is 7x-2 (as all of the h's cancel out)?

Comment: What @user296602 is saying is that you **must write it** in that form.

Comment: @zipirovich I have written it in the required form on a piece of paper. :) It's just very time consuming to type up here.

Comment: I sincerely hope you don't really mean what you've just said. It's time consuming for you to type your question, but you expect other people to make an even more time consuming effort to answer your question?

Comment: @zipirovich OK yes my apologies. I just meant that I would do as he/she said and try to find the answer as quickly and conveniently as possible. No one is obligated to answer my questions. Obviously.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The definition of a *limit*, as already pointed out by other users, can be described as the following:

$$\lim_{h\to0}  \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = f'(x)$$

Now that I've shown you the definition of a *limit*, is this enough information such that you can begin?

Comment: Yes this has helped. Thank you! Is the anwer 7x-2, with all h's eliminated?

Comment: Correct. You can factor out the $h$ from the RHS of the given equation and divide both sides of the equation. The LHS is the definition of a limit, leaving you with your desired answer of $f'(x) = 7x - 2$.